# Zipping GO packages for AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm the author of a foo.go package that my AWS Lambda function handler relies on. The package is not present on GitHub. How should the go files be zipped for AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these things when uploading your GO package to AWS Lambda via AWS Console:

1. The zip should contain not the .go files, but the compiled package. That means that any local packages you rely on can be anywhere you want.
2. When using AWS Console to upload the zipped package to AWS Lambda set the handler name to the binary package name. **Do not** follow the **file-name.handler** handler naming rule. If the package file name is **foo**, the zipped file name is **foo.zip** and the actual handler function name is **bar**, do not set it to **foo.bar**, set it to **foo**.
3. The zip file has to be compatible with linux. If you're working on a Windows machine, use the build-lambda-zip tool. More about the tool at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-go-how-to-create-deployment-package.html